# correct method to get the unsigned char pointer length

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I am using strlen function to get the length of unsigned char pointer. But VS compiler throws the following warning.

```
unsigned char myString[] = "This is my string";
unsigned char* tmpBuffer = &myString[0];
size_t size = strlen(tmpBuffer);

warning C4057: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in indirection to slightly different base types from 'unsigned char *'
```

So what is the proper way to get unsigned char pointer size to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Why do you use `unsigned char`, this look very strange why don't use `char` ?

Comment: That is a sample I have shared. Actual usage is different.

Comment: I think you should change your question to show your actual usage because answer for this question will probably not be correct with your real usage.

Comment: `unsigned char pointer length`..I don't feel too comfortable.

Answer (score 5):

```
strlen((const char*)tmpBuffer);
```

Let you get rid of the note. Here you are typecasting it to the appropriate type that is being expected by the `strlen()`

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.3) the prototype of the function is

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

But here you were passing it of type `unsigned  char*` that's why the complain.

Also if you are using it for simply storing strings as shown in example. You can use `char` without any problem.

Answer (score 5):

Using `strlen` is an O(N) solution to an O(1) problem!

The size of an array is known at *compile time*. Use the idiom `sizeof(myString)`. This is the length **including** the NUL-terminator, so will be 1 greater than the `strlen` result.

Of course, you can't use `sizeof` to obtain the length if the array has *decayed* to a pointer type. In which case, you can obviate the compiler warning by using a cast to `const char*`:

```
size_t size = strlen((const char*)tmpBuffer);
```

noting that the NUL-terminator is **not** included in the count.

The cast is required due to an oddity further back in your code. String literals are of `const char[]` in C, **not** `const unsigned char[]`. Even if `char` is `unsigned` on your platform, `char` and `unsigned char` are still distinct types. It would be better if the first line in your snippet was

```
const char myString[] = "This is my string";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to explicitly cast to a `char*` to get rid of that warning:

```
size_t size = strlen((char*)tmpBuffer);
```

Alternately, since `tmpBuffer` is an array declared in the scope you're in, you can use the `sizeof` operator:

```
size_t size = sizeof(myString) / sizeof(myString[0]) - 1;
```

Comment: `size_t size = sizeof(myString) / sizeof(myString[0]);` => `size_t size = sizeof myString / sizeof *myString - 1;` => `size_t size = sizeof myString - 1;` because `sizeof(unsigned char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather `size_t size = strlen((const char*)tmpBuffer);`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Should it?

Comment: @MichaelWalz That doesn't matter.

Comment: @Stargateur yes, it doesn't matter, but IMO it's "more correct".

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, if you talk about code practice, I think the code is broken by the fact that `myString` is not of type of `char *`(or `char const *`), so... answer can't fix broken design of question. The "more correct" way would be to not need the cast at all ;).